# Filter string to avoid complexity

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have string 'test1' and allowed values 'test1 test2 test3. Is a function to return string if it is in array of values to avoid complicated ifs or cases?

```
'test1'.function(['test1', 'test2', 'test3']) => test1
'test2'.function(['test1', 'test2', 'test3']) => test2
'test5'.function(['test1', 'test2', 'test3']) => nil
```

Regards

Comment: `str if str.in? %w[test1 test2 test3]` would work, see [`in?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-in-3F). If this is a model attribute, you probably want [`validates_inclusion_of`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_inclusion_of).

Comment: in? is i was looking for. thx

Comment: Take a look at [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) too - it is closer to what you asked for (return element from an array that matches certain criteria or return `ifnone` otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own method like

```
def return_present_value(val)
   allow_values = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
   val if allow_values.include? val
end
```

`return_present_value('test1')` will return `test1` and

`return_present_value('test5')` return `nil`